# React native - Start activity from background service

Tags: android, react-native

In my react native app I have a background service which should start an `Activity`. I have made this activity using android SDK and everything is working fine. But I would like to build this activity using react native and also to be invoked from background service.

**How to implement this?**

To get it more clear... App consists of 2 activities and 1 service - first is main activity (RN) and second (SDK) is used to be invoked from service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my year experience it seems `react-navigation` or other app navigators (redux, etc.) has ability to route to specific screen and thus react native does not have to be split to more than one android activity.

Answer (score -1):

Had you ever added Intent Flag?

just like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: I know how to implement this using android SDK. I just want to know how to implement an Activity using react native and start it from background service.

Comment: @matusalem I'm stuck with this problem right now :/
Did you manage to fix it? I'm also not sure if it's possible to control the intent call with React Native, or if I need to go check and edit something in android (java/kotlin) native code...